# Strange lines in between my images

Tags: html, css, image, border, mailchimp

So i've placed some social media buttons on a web page. http://prntscr.com/38xmt9.

As you can see there are black lines in between the images and i have no idea why.

The code for the images:

```
<div class="social_media_wrapper">
   <h3 class="social_media_text">
      Volg ons:
   </h3>
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/Qviv01">
      <img class="social_media_images" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 20px;border: 0;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/b34ec5d84240c7bc42b62c859/images/youtube_icon_256.png" alt="Youtube_icon">
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Qviv.Video">
      <img class="social_media_images" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 20px;border: 0;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/b34ec5d84240c7bc42b62c859/images/facebook_icon_256.png" alt="Facebook_icon">
   </a>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/Qviv">
      <img class="social_media_images" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 20px;border: 0;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/b34ec5d84240c7bc42b62c859/images/twitter_icon_256.png" alt="Twitter_icon">
   </a>
   <a href="https://plus.google.com/106710969799929734976/videos?hl=nl">
      <img class="social_media_images" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 20px;border: 0;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/b34ec5d84240c7bc42b62c859/images/google_plus_icon_256.png" alt="Google_plus_icon">
   </a>
</div>
```

Since it's a fully build page i can't paste all the styling css but here is most of the relevant code:

```
.social_media_wrapper{
    float:right;
    padding-top:20px;
}
.social_media_text{
    float:left;
    font-size:12px !important;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.social_media_images{
    background-image:none !important;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces between the `<a>` and `<img>` tags.

Or add the following to your css:

`.social_media_wrapper a {
     text-decoration:none;
   }`

This removes the underline from the links.

Comment: sweet, i knew the answer had to be simple. I'll accept when the site allows me.

Answer (score 0):

They're the spaces between your `<img>` elements and your closing `</a>` tags.

You can either remove the whitespace in your HTML, or remove the underline of the links.

HTML parsers condense all inline whitespace in your HTML to single spaces (the `<a>` element is an inline element).  They don't remove whitespace completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense to have your `<a>` being set as `inline-block`

```
.social_media_wrapper a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

That way your link embeds the actual image.